# Writing streaming IoT data into MongoDB using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, amazon-web-services

I am working on an IoT project where I need to write streaming data from sensors into MongoDB. I have set up an architecture using AWS IoT Core and AWS Kinesis, and I am using Node.js as my consumer application.

Here is a brief overview of my setup:

IoT devices send data to AWS IoT Core.
AWS IoT Core routes the data to AWS Kinesis.

I have a Node.js consumer application that reads the data from AWS Kinesis and needs to write it into MongoDB.
My MongoDB schema consists of three collections:

```
 - devices collection: Stores information about the IoT devices,
   including device ID, name, and metadata.

 - variables collection: Contains details about the variables being
   monitored by the IoT devices, such as variable ID, name, and unit.

 - data collection: Holds the streaming data from the IoT devices, with
   fields like device ID, variable ID, timestamp, and value.
```

I have successfully set up the streaming pipeline and can see the data flowing through AWS Kinesis. However, I'm unsure about the best approach to write this streaming data into MongoDB efficiently.

My questions are:

What is the recommended approach to consume the streaming data from AWS Kinesis using Node.js?
How can I efficiently write this streaming data into MongoDB in real-time, the rate of data in 2500 data points per minute (data is in json format)?

Any guidance, code examples, or resources would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Maybe have a look on this page: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v5.3/core/timeseries-collections/

Comment: you can have an AWS Lambda consuming data from your kinesis data stream. The lambda can be invoked in batch mode (reading X number of records or every X seconds). That would be the best way. The lambda supports nodejs as a runtime.